# Sticky footer not working when min-width is greater than width of screen (i.e. mobiles devices)

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I **don't** want to be responsive and have set a min-width (of 1024px) to the body and footer so it looks the same on mobile as it does on desktop. Because of this, when viewing the website vertically on mobile, the content will not take up the entirety of the page and so I want to make the footer stick to the bottom of the page.

**Issue:** 
On mobile devices, when viewing the website vertically, the footer is not pushed to the bottom of the screen but instead just to the bottom of the content as if the sticky footer code weren't applied. It works on both my MacBook and iPad, but not on my iPhone or Xiaomi Redmi. I'm guessing it's due to the width of the mobile devices being less than the width of the min-width I set.

The code is basically as follows (from mystrd's modern clean css sticky footer tutorial)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>the title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>the nav</nav>
    <article>the article</article>
    <footer>the footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS is

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
}
footer {
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

My site is http://www.collectthis.com.au where I have applied this exact code. It's working perfectly on MacBook and 12" iPad, but not on iPhone where it [looks like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TwJu.png). As you can see, the footer's over half way up the screen.

I have also tried Ryan Fait's sticky footer code but that doesn't work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` inside the `head` tags is a good start;

Comment: Done. Sorry, new to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can use `vh` (viewport height), `0vh` means "0% of your viewport height" and `100vh` means "100% of your viewport height"

I just changed `bottom: 0` to `top: Calc(100vh - 100px);` (100px is the height of the footer), Calc is a CSS3 function, so it doesn't work on old browsers.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 100px;
}

nav{
  background-color: blue;
  }
footer {
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: Calc(100vh - 100px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>Nav...</nav>
  <article>Article...</article>
  <footer>footer...</footer>
</body>
```

It works on my PC, and it also seems to work on my Android phone.

I hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: Hey there, I've tried your code and it has the same effect. It works on my PC, but not on my iPhone. Although, when I run the code snippet on my iPhone it seems to work. Just not when I run the same code through my website: http://imgur.com/hMvwyf6. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Hi again, so I entered your exact code and it worked. It turns out that I had <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in my header all along (I didn't think this was important), and that made my site mobile friendly or whatever, causing the sticky footer to not act the same on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Could use some more insight into the rest of your css.

when i try this

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
}
footer {
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

(removing the width on your body, changing absolute - fixed in your footer it gets the result you want. But without knowing what else there is I can't do much for more for you.

Comment: Hello, that's literally all of the CSS I have. I've found that there's two different definitions of "sticky footer". I'm after the one that pushes the footer to the bottom of the page when there isn't enough content to fill the page, not the one that follows you when you scroll. That code works if I want to scroll with the footer, but that's not what I was looking for. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I came across this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rws21b21/5/ it might be what you're looking for, or it might give you an idea.